Solve the Alphametic: SOUNDS / WOW = ELK
This is a long-division problem in which letters are substituted for numbers. Solve the problem. Determine the number value of each letter; and when the letters in each one have been arranged in order from 0 to 9, they will spell out a word or words.
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

       ELK
    ------
WOW|SOUNDS
    SLIL
    ----
      NNDS
      NSOU
      ----
       OIO
```


Let's start with the obvious.

 In the first subtraction, we see N - L = N, and we also have no subtraction for the L in the quotient, so L must be 0. Since we now have O - 0 = 0, O must be 1 and U - I = N must force a borrow. Now we have:
         E0K
     ------
 W1W|S1UNDS
     S0I0
     ----
       NNDS
       NS1U
       ----
        1I1

Next,

 notice that we have W * E = 0 in our first multiplication. This means that either W or E must be 5 and the other must be even. However, in the second multiplication, W * K = U; if W were 5, it can only produce a product ending in 5 or 0, and U can be neither of those. So E must be 5, though that doesn't help us much as there's only the one E in the puzzle:
         50K
     ------
 W1W|S1UNDS
     S0I0
     ----
       NNDS
       NS1U
       ----
        1I1

However,

 we can find out some more about W, since it's also the first digit in the divisor. WOW is either 212, 414, 616, or 818, and we know that it's multiplied by 5 to yield S0I0, meaning S0I0 is either 1060, 2070, 3080, or 4090. We can rule out the first of these since 1 is already taken. We can also rule out the second by noticing that S - U = 1 in the last division, and if S was 2, U would be 1. Finally, notice in that same division that N - S = 1 (and we know there's no borrow as the only option that would force a borrow would mean D = 0, also a contradiction), so if S was 4, N would equal 5, which is already taken. Therefore, we must have S = 3, I = 8, and W = 6, and we can expand that to N = 4 and U = 2:
         50K
     ------
 616|3124D3
     3080
     ----
       44D3
       4312
       ----
        181

All that's left now is

 to find D and K. We have D - 1 = 8, so D must be 9, and we can use process of elimination to find K, but we could also divide 4312 by 616 to get K = 7, and that's more fun, so let's do that.

Here's the final division problem:

         507
     ------
 616|312493
     3080
     ----
       4493
       4312
       ----
        181

Putting it all together, we get our final solution:

 0123456789
LOUSNEWKID


Slightly different solve path:

 From N-L=N in the first subtraction, we get L=0, from O-0=0 we get that O=1 and 1U-I=N.
 In the second subtraction we find that N-S=1, and since S-U cannot use a borrow (that requires S=0), S-U is also 1. Connecting the last three equations yields I=8, which in turn yields D=9.
 The first subtraction involves a quantity x080. This must be 5 times the divisor, which must in turn be 616, yielding E=5 and W=6. U, S, and N must now be the only three consecutive unclaimed numbers (2, 3, and 4), and K the only number left (7).

